# Override HttpContext.Current.Request.Url property in c# to return the encoded URL

Tags: c#, overriding, handler

In one of my applications I am using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` in `aspx` code to get the current page `url`. As the page `url` is being used in java script there is a high chance of passing malicious script in the `url` to make the JS function to break.

One option is that we can encode the `url` using

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url)
```

but this piece of code is a part of user control (`.ascx file`), I have to change that in all those user control.

So is there any way I can override the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

property so that it will return the encoded `url`? So I can use some handler to  tackle all the `url` property in application?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` because the method is a static method.

But I think you can try to use an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to do yours expect.

```
public static class UriExtension {
    public static string HtmlEncode(this Uri uri){
        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(uri);
         // do the logic...

    }
}
```

You can call the method

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.HtmlEncode()
```